# what is the interior and the closure of $\{4\}$ and of $\{2,4,6,8.....\}$?

Tags: general-topology

let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ . Set $A_n = \{ n , n+1, n+2,....\} $ and $ T = \{ \emptyset , A_n\}_{ n\in \mathbb{N} }$

$1.$Is  $T $is separated ?

$2.$ what are dense  set in $T$ ?

$3.$ what is the interior and the  closure of $\{4\}$  and of $\{2,4,6,8.....\}$?

My attempt :  for  $ 1,$  I know  that $ T$ is not separated because  take $A_1 = \{ 1, 2,3,...\}$ and $A_2 = \{ 2, 3,4,,,,,,,\}$ here both $A_1 \cap A_2 \ne \emptyset$

For  $2)$ i thinks  $\mathbb{N} $

For $3)$ im confused

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Please use \emptyset to denote the empty set, not $\phi$!

Comment: @B.Swan okkss..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$ Actually, $A_n\cap A_m\neq \emptyset$ for every $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$. That should help you prove that no pair of points can be separated.

$2)$ A subspace $S$ is dense when its closure $\overline{S}$ is the whole space. A point $x\in\overline{S}$ is a point for which every neighbourhood contains a point of $S$. It is not hard to prove that $S$ is dense if and only if $S$ is infinite. If $S$ is finite, then it has a maximum element $s_0$, so any point $s>s_0$ has a neighbourhood which does not intersect $S$. Similarly, if for every $n\in \Bbb{N}$ there is a neighbourhood containing a point in $S$, then $S$ must be infinite.

$3)$ Their interior is empty because no open set is contained in $\{4\}$ nor in $\{2,4,6,\dots\}$.

Comment: thanks u javi,,

Answer (score 1):

Your answers:

1) Incorrect. The fact that two particular open sets intersect does not imply at all that the topology is not separated. You should pick two natural numbers $m,n$ (call $m$ the lesser one, for example) and try to show that this points can not be separated.

2) Incorrect. Of course $\Bbb N$ is dense. But how are the closed sets? What would be the closure of the set of, say, even numbers?

For the third one, perhaps you have a clearer idea of how the topology is. Good try!

Comment: .okss  @ajotatxe for 2)   i thinks  ur assumption is wrong  why are  r u taking even number ?   for  third i think interior of$ \{4\}= \emptyset$ and closure $\{4\} = \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @jasmine The closure of $\{4\}$ is $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Try showing that, if an open set contains $1$, $2$, or $3$, then it must contain $4$. Also, if $n > 4$, then try finding an open set that contains $n$ but not $4$. (Or just write out all the closed sets, and find the smallest one that contains $4$.)

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks u